# Smarty foreach mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, smarty

Have some trouble with foreach in smarty.

php

```
$rows4 = array(); 
   $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"); 
   while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4)) { 
   $rows4[] = $row4; 
    } 

   $rows45 = array(); 
   $result45 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1"); 
   while($row45 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result45)) { 
   $rows45[] = $row45; 
    } 

/** assign variable */ 

$smarty->assign('rows4', $rows4); 
$smarty->assign('rows45', $rows45);
```

tpl

```
{foreach $rows4 as $row4} 
    <tr> 
       <td><center>{$row4.datum|truncate:10:""}</center></td> 
       <td><center>{$row4.count|truncate:10:""} {$row45.count}</center></td> 
     </tr> 
      {/foreach}
```

But how can I assign the second query in this foreach now, this dont work:

```
{foreach $rows4 as $row4 || $rows45 as $row45} 
    <tr> 
       <td><center>{$row4.datum|truncate:10:""}</center></td> 
       <td><center>{$row4.count|truncate:10:""} {$row45.count}</center></td> 
     </tr> 
      {/foreach}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a foreach loop for two arrays in the same time? And what is the result that you want to get?

Comment: I need these two results and want display them in tpl in the same foreach, maybe better solution? thx

Comment: Please mention what your trying to do,both of your queries look the same so instead of running 2 diffrent queries you could just pull the first 6 results and manipulate them the way you want.BTW there is no reason to use mysql_* functions

Comment: Yes i can get the 6 results in one query but how to manipulate that the 6th result don't get show ? I want only to get the day displayed on one tpl like you see up in the tpl example (foreach). thx

Comment: I dont understand anything from your code,cant understand what you want to do,provide the list given from query and the way you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rows445 = array();
$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
    $rows445[]['row4'] = $row4;
}

$result45 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_follow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1");
while ($row45 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result45)) {
    $rows445[]['row45'] = $row45;
}

/** assign variable */    
$smarty - > assign('rows445', $rows445);
```

Comment: This bring me nothing because i need two array data in the foreach in tpl

Answer (score 0):

I you get the same number of results in `$row4` and `$row45` then you can use an increment:

```
    {assign var=i value=0}
    {foreach $rows4 as $row4} 
    {assign var=row45 value=$rows45[i]}
        <tr> 
            <td><center>{$row4.datum|truncate:10:""}</center></td> 
            <td><center>{$row4.count|truncate:10:""} {$row45.count}</center></td> 
        </tr> 
    {assign var=i value=$i+1}
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with increment... $row4.count is example. 1240 and $row45.count 8450

Comment: So i don't understand why you want to display them on the same foreach ?

Comment: Because i have a table that must display two variables from mysql (2 querys) in the same foreach

Comment: Can't you be more explicit please? Because it can be another way to do this.

Comment: http://www11.pic-upload.de/06.04.15/ce5kme8zr2a.png , the first query show (1) the second show (2) but i can not display bot in foreach if i add another foreach in tpl i get 5x5=25 rows ... :S thx

Comment: What's the difference between $row45.count and $row4.count? Because on the SQL query, i see no difference except the OFFSET. The count will always be 5 (you set the limit to 5).

Comment: Yes its the same query but i need that i $row45.count the last row get skipped, thats because the offset.